# Missing app from AppGallery after publishing update

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I have sent an update of my App to Huawei a few days ago. Verification went well, no remarks by Huawei side. Yesterday's update has been published, but the app was missed from appgallery. The update did not come to users. They can't find an app throw search. But the link to the app is working on a [desktop browser](https://appgallery.huawei.com/#/app/C102945305). On phones can't find app across AppGallery. Huawei did not send me any info. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

According to the confirmation with the review team, when they try to log in your app for the first time on the **HMS phone** (*mate30, HMS, emui11.0.0*), the following error message is always displayed before login.

[image]

Although they could log in after loading the app for a period of time, but this problem does not occur on the **GMS phone**(mate20pro).

To solve the issue, you are recommended to test your app in HMS devices to reproduce and optimize its incompatibility issues against non-GMS devices.

Comment: I have 2 devices with HMS. huawei p40 lite and honor 30i. And its perfectly work on it. Can review team test the app again? Maybe problem was on server side. Or I should send app to review team again?

Comment: hi@ПавелСухарев, Thank you for your feedback. Just reconfirmed with the review team, you do not need to resubmit the apk, they will reprocess your application within 1-3 days. You can search for it again at that time. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. I tested app on service "Cloud Debugging" from AppGallery Connect. Phone "Huawei P40 pro (Harmony Os 1.2.0)" and it's work perfectly. I recorded a video with proof and can send it to you, if need. If you say me where i should send.

Comment: hi@ПавелСухарев, you could send it to hmscore@huawei.com, then i will feed this back to the review team, and will contact you as soon as if i have any progress.

Comment: hi@ПавелСухарев, the review team has just reported that the problem has been handled. You can search for your app on non-GMS devices again. NOTE: If you have any queries, please feel free to contact us. Thank you.